# windows phone binding data

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I'm working with windows phone 8 apps that getting data from restful service using json file and I getting problem to showing data I get from restful service into my listbox here is the code:

> ```
>             WebClient client = new WebClient();
>             client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,e) =>
>                 {
>                     if(e.Error == null){
>                         RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
>                         CurrentDay = new ObservableCollection<Item>(result.results.items);
>                         MessageBox.Show(CurrentDay[3].title.ToString());
>                     }else{
>                         MessageBox.Show("Sorry, try again at the next TechEd");
>                     }
>                 };
>             client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=37.7851%2C-122.4047&cat=transport&tf=plain&pretty=true&app_id=xxxxx&app_code=xxxxx"));
> ```

the app_id and app_code sensored sorry :P

in that code i can't show the data into my listbox but when i using it showing the right data

> MessageBox.Show(CurrentDay[3].title.ToString());

oh and I'm using mvvm light reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your ListBox has `ItemsSource` Property set to `CurrentDay`.

If that is true, the ListBox needs to know that the property was changed.

Since you are using `ObservableCollection`, the ListBox will notice chances to the current collection (e.g Add or Remove `Items`), but it can't know that a new `ObservableCollection` is assigned to the property unless you notify it.

To make it simple, I suggest you to Clear the `CurrentDay` collection and Add items to it, instead of creating a `new ObservableCollection<Item>()` each time:

```
CurrentDay.Clear();
foreach (var item in result.results.items)
    CurrentDay.Add(item);
```

Make sure to initialize the collection in the constructor:

```
CurrentDay = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
```

Comment: yes itemsource set to current day... so how to clear the current day collection and add items to it?

Comment: solved by using INotifyPropertyChanged method that show in databound app template... thank you very much